# Custom Binding not working updating from Knockout 2.3 to 3.3

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, windows-8.1

My Windows 8.1 App was working fine on Knockout 2.3 but after updating to 3.3 it seems like I get the wrong Context in my custom binding.

First here is how I apply binding for individual elements in the command bar of my app :

```
var cmdArray = [];
    var commandIsRunning = function() {
        return _.any(cmdArray, function(command) {
            return command.isRunning();
        });
    };
    _.each(_bottomCommands, function (row) {
        if(row.command) {
            // command wrapper
            var commandWrapper = ko.command({
                action: function() {
                    var rowCommand = row.command();
                    if (rowCommand) {
                        return rowCommand();
                    }
                    return WinJS.Promise.as();
                },
                canExecute: function() {
                    var rowCommand = row.command();
                    if (rowCommand) {
                        return rowCommand.canExecute() && !commandIsRunning();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            cmdArray.push(commandWrapper);

            //Bind the command
            var element = document.querySelector('#' + row.id);
            if (element) {
                element.setAttribute('data-bind', 'command: $data');
                ko.applyBindings(commandWrapper, element);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my custom binding code

```
ko.bindingHandlers.command = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var command = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                ko.bindingHandlers.click.init.call(this, element, ko.observable(command), allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                var command = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                ko.bindingHandlers.enable.update.call(this, element, command.canExecute, allBindingsAccessor);
            }
        };
```

The problem is in:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enable.update.call(this, element, command.canExecute, allBindingsAccessor);
```

`canExecute` is undefined which I think is because I am not getting the right context in the `init` and `update` handlers. So what am I doing wrong in my code?  Again the code was working in Knockout 2.3 , so could it be a Knockout issue?

**UPDATE:**
I created jsFiddle to show the problem. It contains the definition for `ko.command` because I thought that could be the cause of problem
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrb97g7e/31/)

Comment: Can you include this in a code snippet so that we can play arount with it?

Comment: @JotaBe I updated my question.

Comment: You may need to tweak your fiddle a bit - for both knockout 3 and 2.3 I'm seeing "Unable to process binding "command: function (){return $data }", Message: d is not a function"

Comment: @JamesThorpe Actually that is exactly my problem. I put two debuggers in my fiddle code. if you stop on the second one you see that  `command.canExecute` is  _undefined_ . that is why you get the error

Comment: `command.canExecute` is undefined on the second debugger in both versions of knockout - `command` itself appears to be a function that returns a promise

Comment: @JamesThorpe Fiddle code is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because Knockout 3.x binds to functions differently. In 2.x, you could bind directly to a function, but in 3.x, Knockout calls the function to get the viewmodel. You can still bind to a function in Knockout 3.x, but you'll need to wrap it in an observable or in another function.

```
ko.applyBindings(function() { return commandWrapper }, element);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbest/nrb97g7e/38/